# The mystery of the skull

Tags: riddle, symbols

[image]

**Puzzle:** Identify whose skull is depicted at the bottom of this Russian icon.

**Bonus Point 1:** Identify the two items depicted on either side of the cross.

Comment: Care to explain why so many downvotes? I'm new to Puzzling.SE so any constructive feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Russian "Golgotha's Cross" (Greek letter Γ stands for G in russian Golgothas in Greek) (or Calvary Cross)
The items are: the spear (that penetrated Jesus' body) and the sponge (with vinegar) during Crucifixion.
Skull of Adam

Comment: Golgothas is standing for ΚΡΑΝΙΟΥ ΤΟΠΟΣ (Κraniou topos) in Greek, which means "the place of the skull") which is the term used in the gospels (that were written in Greek). The term is still in use in modern Greek ,also metaphorically.